# Unwrapping and Texturing a Sphere

Tags: modeling, uv

I've been trying to unwrap this christmas ball, and add glitter normal map to it, but the seems are too visible.

Is there any way to apply a normal map that ignore the seams, or a better way to unwrap it?

[image]

Comment: Personally I would try to use Generated mapping, why not even box projection with some blend on the texture file, bake that into a new texture, and then use that baked texture with UVs.